# Detect multitasking gestures on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPad app,

- If any app is running we can move the app horizontally by dragging the app screen horizontally by two or three fingers.

It is an inbuilt feature of an iPad, right.

**Is there any notification or somethig so that I can be notified? When this happens.**

Is there any way so that Ican disable this feature for my app.?

Code:-
WHILE TOUCHES MOVED CALL MY MAIN VIEW IS DISABLED AS REQUIREMENT, SO WHEN I AM DRAGGING THE SCREEN  AS DESCRIBED ABOVE EVERYTHING FREEZS.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

   if(self.tag==trackCell && (trackLifeCycle==1 || trackLifeCycle==2) && trackCell!=-2)
   {

    if(![[self superview] isKindOfClass:[AQGridView class]])
    {  
        //NSLog(@"Touches Moved");

        trackLifeCycle=2;

        //////NSLog(@"Touches Moved at cell  Starts%d",self.tag);     
        UITouch *T=[touches anyObject];

        self.center=[T locationInView:[self superview]];

        [delegate isOnHeaderView:self center:self.center];

        //////NSLog(@"Touches Moved at cell Ends %d",self.tag);

    }
   }



}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: The two-finger horizontal scrolling is not an “inbuilt feature of an iPad”.  It can be a feature of a `UIScrollView`, but only if the `UIScrollView` is set up for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I am asking about multitasking gesture recognizer for iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multitasking gestures use four or five fingers.  You cannot disable them from within your app.  The user can disable them for all apps in the Settings app (under the General section).

There is no notification specifically for the multitasking gestures.  You will get `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` when the user begins the gesture.  If the user ends the gesture without switching apps, you will get `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.  If the user does switch apps, you will get `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification` (which might not be public) and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`.

If you had active touches when the user began the multitasking gesture, each touched view should get a `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` message, and each active gesture recognizer should set its own `state` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` and send its action messages.

Comment: Thanks Rob but scrolling is not a problem the problem is when ever app is scrolled to another app horizontally, By gesture recognizer.

Comment: It is an inbuit feature of iPAd.I think you got it.